# Is it possible to change cached Container folder name?

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I am currently working on the project that has over 20 cron jobs. Some of them are pretty long processes. It was built on Symfony 2.8, so we decided to upgrade it to 3.4 LTS.

After the upgrade we noticed that, if there is ongoing cron job (long process) and we push some changes to Prod environment we get this error:

```
Fatal Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/.../cache/prod/
```

Turns out, that when we deploy the changes, cached container (in var/cache/prod/ContainerXXXXXX) changed the XXXXXX value. Or in other words, we clear the cache (during deploy) and then it generates new Container in cache directory. More about this problem: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25654 .

So, my question (and idea) is, is it possible to make cache Container directory name always the same? Maybe any ideas how?

Comment: Have you tried using different adapter, like memcached? https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/cache/adapters/memcached_adapter.html

Comment: Or write your own adapter that will extend symfony cache adapter but rewrites `getFile` method

Comment: @Justinas thank you for your response! Can memcached cache compiled container files? What I found its key-value cache adapter. I'll try create own adapter.

Comment: You really should consider stopping the cron jobs before deploying then restarting them.  Even if you get past the container issue you will still have the case where your cron code might either be using your old code or, even worse, might try loading some of the new code.  All kinds of "not fun" things can happen.

Comment: @Cerad You are right, but I think we still could try to get new container name after process ends and try to load it.